# Crashing .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

In a recent interview for a C# development position I was asked for a code example which can crash the .NET Framework. I didn't and still don't know the answer to this question.

Any ideas?

Comment: very poor interview question.

Comment: You should have asked them to clarify

Comment: Another useless interview question.  I would have said that I didn't know, because I don't write code that crashes the VM.

Comment: Do you mean code that will throw an exception (that's incredibly easy), or what?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but there's a good chance that a devious and scheming mind could design a class in such a way that gets the Garbage Collector angry.  And as we all know, 'anger leads to fear, fear leads to hate, and hate leads to the dark side'.  And in technical terms, that translates to a Framework crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They may have meant code that throws an exception; however, that would be a very strange question.

If not, they're asking for interop.
You can crash a .Net application by calling native code incorrectly.

Comment: Alternatively, simply unsafe code and... (your choice... including) start fiddling with string internals and change the first two bytes of data (that specifies string length); trying to access memory at addresses less than 64K; unmanaged interop; manipulate type data information (void *ptr = &(myObj.GetType()); *(ptr + 4) = myObj.GetHashCode();); etc etc

Comment: I will accept this answer. I am sure they were not looking for a simple exception throwing answer but more likely a dirty native call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't crash the framework, you can crash applications that use the framework.

One good example is to add an infinitely recursive method to an application without any exception handling.

Comment: Here's the thing: you *can* crash the framework; MSFT periodically issues reliability updates that essentially patch the Framework to reduce how often this happens. It's sorta hard (to do so without meaning to), but that's not to say that it's impossible.

But basically the interview question is badly articulated and vague.

Comment: @GGulati: Agreed, but it's not the framework that crashes per se, it's the application, right. For example, if you have 10 applications running that use the framework (not including asp.net) and one performs an operation that causes its instance of the framework to crash, that application crashes, not all of the applications. I think it's really a matter of semantics. And it's a terrible interview question asked by someone who probably thinks they are far more clever than they actually are.

Comment: I would guess that one could also crash CLR which is a part of the framework

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a trick question and that they're looking for you to say that it's not possible to crash the framework itself (i.e., somehow take down all running .net application) using your own code.  As others have mentioned any framework crashes would be a result of buggy code in the framework itself which would likely be addressed quickly by Microsoft.